# I Got A "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" And A "DeprecationWarning" When Trying To Run The Code For The Bot, Any Solution To Fix This Problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im Trying To Make A Discord Bot For A Server, I Entered "`node .`" into the terminal to run the bot and i got this error:

```
    (node:17632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided.
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Thela\code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\ClientManager.js:48:41)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at WebSocketConnection.onClose (C:\Users\Thela\code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:390:10)
    at WebSocket.onClose (C:\Users\Thela\code\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:124:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at WebSocket.emitClose (C:\Users\Thela\code\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:191:10)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnClose (C:\Users\Thela\code\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:850:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at net.js:658:12
(node:17632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either 
by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:17632) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

In The Terminal.
This Is The index.js file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

And Here Is The config.json:

```
{
"prefix": "!",
"token": "7F2x4ct0AMuBeJKZUGmtIz_RZVKve-N4"
}
```

i realised i didnt put the full error
   oops

Comment: Is it safe to post the token here...?

Comment: the real error is `Error: Incorrect login details were provided.`. The `Promise` part is another question.

Comment: @appleapple it's not another error, It looks like it's the login promise not being handled witch is what's causing the error in the first place.

Comment: @ThomasReichmann promise rejection is not the real error, the problem here is the promise **should not** been rejected at first place.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using as "token" is actually your client secret, the token should look something like this:

NjQwOTM2MjE3MTg5Mjg1ODg4.XcGSOQ.3dgX4GbvEDZKYHnCb6nJORuvL1w

Comment: Yeah I Know That, And It Is In The Code With The Line In The config.json
`"token": "7F2x4ct0AMuBeJKZUGmtIz_RZVKve-N4"`

also yes ik i have shown my token and i did regenerate it

Comment: You didn't understand me, I know your token is in the config file, what you had in the config file wasn't your token, it was your client secret, just compare the two, one is way shorter than the other.
Go to the discord dashboard, create a bot and get the actual bot token